# SItecore 8.2.6 - IndexField attribute is not recognized in code

Tags: indexing

[image: Visual Studio Code Screenshot]

IndexField attribute is not recognized although Sitecore.ContentSearch.dll reference is added and namespace is included.

Comment: And if you hover over the IndexField, does it say you need to add another reference maybe?

Comment: Unfortunately No. It asks to generate the class.

Comment: Does your  project reference `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq`?

Comment: Great. It fixed the issue after adding the Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq reference. Thank you very much Marek.

Comment: Excellent! Comment converted into an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a reference to

```
Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq.dll
```

Not only to `Sitecore.ContentSearch.dll`